# Adding dynamic links using NavigateURL on ASP.NET (VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, label, placeholder, navigateurl

I Have this code in my page, and I want that every NavigateUrl display another page like :
`simple.aspx?id=1`, `simple.aspx?id=2`, ...

Where id = `c`

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
 Dim c As Integer = 0
  While c < 5
   Dim Label1 As New Label()
   Dim ltr As New Literal()     
   Dim link As New HyperLink()
   link.NavigateUrl = "simple.aspx"
   link.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Aqua            
   Label1.Text = c.ToString()
   ltr.Text = "<br/>"
   PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(Label1)
   PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(link)
   PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ltr)
   c += 1
   End While
   End Sub
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
 Dim c As Integer = 0
  While c < 5
   Dim Label1 As New Label()
   Dim ltr As New Literal()     
   Dim link As New HyperLink()
   link.NavigateUrl = "simple.aspx?id=" & c.tostring
   link.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Aqua            
   Label1.Text = c.ToString()
   ltr.Text = "<br/>"
   PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(Label1)
   PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(link)
   PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ltr)
   c += 1
   End While
   End Sub
```